# NODEJS parse cell value get from google sheets

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, google-sheets

I get value from cell range from google sheets using REST api, this is my response from google sheets

```
{
  "range": "RECORD!A2:J2",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": [
    [
      "07/11/2016",
      "21:20:10",
      "3",
      "MAIN",
      "Nam",
      "1",
      "xxxxxxxxxxx",
      "xxxxxxxxxxx",
      "xxxxxxxxxxx",
      "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I try to use JSON.parse() method. Here my code

```
var data = JSON.parse(response);              //reponse store presponse from google sheets
var data_values = resposne.values[0];
```

How I get data from values[0]? like:

```
var DAY = values[0][0];
var TIME = values[0][1];
var NO = values[0][2];
var OBJECT = values[0][3];
var NAME = values[0][4];
.........
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(var i=0;i<response.values.length;i++){
  for(var j=0;j<response.values[i].length;i++){
          var DAY = values[i][j];
          var TIME = values[i][j];
          var NO = values[i][j];
          var OBJECT = values[i][j];
          var NAME = values[i][j];
  }
}
```